# How to increment MySQL Id column value by 1 with powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

My script is working and I can input the value I want into a MySQL database. This script will be running on a schedule and I need the ID field to increment by 1. I tried a simple starting value of 1 assigned to a variable and ++, but the value isn't held in memory and there's probably a better way to make this happen. Here's what I'm working with. I need the value in the ID column to increment 1 every time this script runs and updates the database.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$constr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=mydb;user id=root;password=P@ssw0rd"
$con = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = $constr
$con.Open()
$cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(@id, @text, @date, @datetime)"
$cmd.Connection = $con
$cmd.Prepare()
$today = get-date
$cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = 1
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1)
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", $totalSessions.count)
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", $today)
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", $today)
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$con.close()
```

output

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| id   | text       | date_val   | date_time           |
+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|    1 | Text Value | 2020-04-21 | 2020-04-21 15:54:54 |
|    1 | Text Value | 2020-04-21 | 2020-04-21 15:57:05 |
|    1 | Text Value | 2020-04-21 | 2020-04-21 16:02:12 |
+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you aware of auto-increment fields in mysql? If you update the column type, you can then just ignore that one in the insert and the database will do it for you.

Comment: I am brand new to mysql. Are you saying you don't have to do anything to the id column? just leave it blank and it will auto increment?

Comment: And what change would I have to make in the script to allow that? Simply removing the "1" from $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1) 
doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with an always increasing `id` that *may have gaps*, the simplest option is to declare that column as `auto_increment`:

```
create table test (
    myid int auto_increment primary key,
    mytext varchar(50),
    mydate date,
    mydatetime datetime
);
```

On the other hand, if you do want a strictly incremental id, another solution is to retrieve the maximum value from the table itself, using an `insert ... select ...` query:

```
insert into test(myid, mytext, mydate, mydatetime)
select coalesce(max(myid), 0) + 1, @text, @date, @datetime
from test
```

Comment: so I created a new table to test with by running
.......
create table test2 (
    -> id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    -> vdi_users varchar(50),
    -> date
    -> datetime
    -> );
.....

But I had to comment out and remove anywhere I referenced @id in my pwsh code to make it work. Now there is no ID field...what do I need to use in code to get the ID column back and have it auto increment?

Comment: @dcvl: the `id` column is in the table, and it auto-increments everytime you `insert`. Just `select` from the table and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ID column to auto increment by itself, then you only need to worry about adding new rows and MySQL will do the rest.

```
mysql> create table NextIdDemo
   -> (
   -> id int auto_increment,
   -> primary key(id)
   -> );
```

If the database is already live and you don't want to drop and create again, you can simply update the column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN test_col_id INT auto_increment
```

Check [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql) if you want more information.